# Change LED color for sms in android

Tags: android, colors, led

How to change color of LED for sms notifications. I can change the color of LED, but the problem is when sms is received it shows the default LED color. Unless I clear the sms notification. And then it shows my LED color.

Code is here:

```
package com.example.led;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    String phoneNumber = "";
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            phoneNumber = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        if(phoneNumber.equals("+1234567890")) {
            NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notif.setLights(0x990000, 100, 100);
            notif.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notif.setContentTitle("Notification Title");
            nm.notify(5, notif.build());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Sender: " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did u create LED on android app ? post your code too for people to help you

Comment: You can't control how other apps issue their own `Notification`s.

Comment: I am doing it in receiver.

Comment: @MikeM. yeah but can I put my notification on top of all other notifications?

Comment: @Redman see my edit post I have added the code in it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You can try calling `setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)` on your `Notification.Builder`. If the default SMS app issues at a lower priority, yours should override it.

Comment: Now, the notification is always on the top. But the LED color is default not the one I wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I should've said "it _might_ override it". Well, then it's probably first come, first serve for the LED, and the default app is going to get the message before your app.

Comment: But the thing is I want to show my LED Color even if it receives text messages. How would I do this?